# Read wide file with repeated variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have input data shaped like this:

```
var1 var2 var3 var2 var3 ...
```

where each row has one value of `var1` followed by a varying number of `var2`-`var3` pairs. After reading this input, I want the data set to have multiple records for each `var1`: one record for each pair of `var2`/`var3`.

So if the first two lines of the input file are

```
A 1 2 7 3 4 5
B 2 3
```

this would generate 4 records:

```
A 1 2
A 7 3
A 4 5
B 2 3
```

Is there an simple/elegant way to do this? I've tried reading each row as one long variable and splitting with `scan` but it's getting messy and I'm betting there's a really easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but here is the first that comes to my mind:

```
data want(keep=var1 var2 var3);
  infile 'path-to-your-file';
  input;
  var1 = input(scan(_infile_,1),$8.);
  i = 1;
  do while(i ne 0);
     i + 1;
     var2 = input(scan(_infile_,i),8.);
     i + 1;
     var3 = input(scan(_infile_,i),8.);
     if var3 = . then i = 0;
     else output;
     end;
run;
```

`_infile_` is an automatic SAS variable that contains the currently read record. Use an appropriate `informat` for each variable you read.

Answer (score 1):

Like this (conditional input with jumping back):

```
data test;
infile datalines missover;
input var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ temp $ @;
output;
do while(not missing(temp));
    input  +(-2) var2 $  var3 $ temp $ @;
    output;
end;
drop temp;
datalines;
A 1 2 7 3 4 5
B 2 3
;
run;
```

Comment: Very nice! I'll have to read a bit about the `+(-2)` notation, but this looks great. Thanks!